# Only include first N occurrences of secondary column in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do in pandas what I would do with a correlated subquery in SQL, and have not been able to figure out a non-iterative and/or speedier solution. Consider a (much larger) dataframe of players, games, and stats for those games, which could be defined as such:

```py
import pandas as pd

def make_mock_df():
    mock_data = {
        "player": ["Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim"],
        "game_id": ["red", "red", "green", "green", "blue", "red", "yellow", "yellow", "blue", "blue"],
        "stat_id": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
        "value": [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2],
    }
    return pd.DataFrame(mock_data)
```

In reality, the game ID would be a UUID, and the data would already be sorted first by player and then by game date, recent-first.

What I want to do is create a dataframe that averages each stat type over the last N games per player. This gets tricky, as not every player plays every game (mocked in the data), and thus is why I'd do the correlated subquery in SQL. This is the iterative solution so far, which breaks down the dataframe by player, then concats each limited player dataframe to rebuild the whole:

```py
def filter_last_n_games(df, n_games):
    last_n_games_per_player = pd.DataFrame()

    for _, player_group in df.groupby("player"):
        # this works because games are sorted already
        # and appear sorted in the unique() series as well
        last_n_games = player_group.game_id.unique()[0:n_games]
        # can't do nlargest because games have string IDs
        last_n_mask = player_group.game_id.isin(last_n_games)
        player_last_n = player_group[last_n_mask]
        # build up last N games df piece by piece...
        last_n_games_per_player = pd.concat(
            [last_n_games_per_player, player_last_n]
        )

    return last_n_games_per_player

def avg_stats_last_n_games(df, n_games):
    last_n_games_per_player = filter_last_n_games(df, n_games)

    # calculate averages per game (easy part)
    last_n_avgs = (
        last_n_games_per_player
        .groupby(["player", "stat_id"])
        .mean()
        .filter(["player", "stats_id", "value"])
        .rename(columns={"value": "avg_value"})
    )

    return last_n_avgs
```

And results in output as such:

```
stats_df = make_mock_df()
avg_stats_last_n_games(stats_df, 2)
>>>                 avg_value
>>> player stat_id           
>>> Bob    1              1.5
>>>        2              3.5
>>> Jim    1              1.0
>>>        2              2.0
```

Is there a better substitute for the `filter_last_n_games()` function that would fully take advantage of pandas' capabilities and allow me to ditch the for-loop?

Comment: not able to replicate your solution with your functions, `gdf = make_mock_df(); filter_last_n_games(gdf, 2); print(avg_stats_last_n_games(gdf, 2).to_dict())`, I am getting `{('Bob', 1): 1.5, ('Bob', 2): 3.5, ('Jim', 1): 1.0, ('Jim', 2): 2.0}`

Comment: @DOOM Sorry -- your output is correct, I'd flipped the Bobs and Jims and forgot to recopy the results. Edited above to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

For each group, to select last `n` games requires,

1. total #'s elements in the group `tcount`.
2. tagging elements in the group index count `icount`.

For the mock dataframe,

```py
# With your `make_mock_df()` I am getting

#   player game_id  stat_id  value
# 0    Bob     red        1      1
# 1    Bob     red        2      3
# 2    Bob   green        1      2
# 3    Bob   green        2      4
# 4    Bob    blue        1      3
# 5    Jim     red        1      1
# 6    Jim  yellow        1      1
# 7    Jim  yellow        2      2
# 8    Jim    blue        1      4
# 9    Jim    blue        2      2

def add_counters(grp):
    grp['tcount'] = grp.shape[0]
    grp['icount'] = np.arange(grp.shape[0]) + 1
    return grp


gdf = make_mock_df()
gdf = gdf.groupby(['player', 'game_id']).apply(lambda x: add_counters(x))

# Selecting last `N` games
N=2;

gdf = gdf[(gdf['tcount'] >= N) & (gdf['icount'] <= N)]

# After this filtering step i Get
#   player game_id  stat_id  value  tcount  icount
# 0    Bob     red        1      1       2       1
# 1    Bob     red        2      3       2       2
# 2    Bob   green        1      2       2       1
# 3    Bob   green        2      4       2       2
# 6    Jim  yellow        1      1       2       1
# 7    Jim  yellow        2      2       2       2
# 8    Jim    blue        1      4       2       1
# 9    Jim    blue        2      2       2       2


gdf.groupby(['player', 'stat_id'])[['value']].agg('mean').rename(columns={'value': 'avg_value'})

#                 avg_value
# player stat_id
# Bob    1              1.5
#        2              3.5
# Jim    1              2.5
#        2              2.0
```

### Check the edits above

Comment: Hmm, output doesn't match. Not sure I see how the counters relate to being able to only consider the last N games, if they're related to the number of stats per game — and maybe I should clarify, we're assuming the games have already been sorted most recent first. So if N = 2, for Bob, we'd want average stats for the "red" and "green" games, and for Jim we'd want to consider the "red" and "yellow" games. When I print `gdf` after applying the tcount/icount mask, Bob has the "red" and "green" games, but Jim has "yellow" and "blue".

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the equalivant to doing a subquery:

```
(df[df.groupby(['player','stat_id']).cumcount() < 2] #filter dataframe to first two records
   .groupby(['player','stat_id'])['value'].mean())  #then groupby and take average
```

Output:

```
player  stat_id
Bob     1          1.5
        2          3.5
Jim     1          1.0
        2          2.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```